# Find the smallest prime number by which the given expression is divided by

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $z_1=3-4i$ and $z_2=2+i$, $\alpha \not =1$ and $\alpha^6=1$.
>   The sum S=$\sum _{r=0}^{5} |z_1+z_2\alpha^r|^2$ is divisible by which smallest prime number

$$|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1+z_2\alpha|^2....|z_1+z_2\alpha^5|^2$$
I know that $\alpha=\cos \pi/3+i\sin \pi/3$

$$34+|3+2\alpha+i(\alpha-4)|^2....$$and so on. I can’t really get anywhere from there. How should I proceed?

Comment: "I know that α=cosπ/3+isinπ/3"  No, you don't.  You know that that is one of five values that it might be.

Comment: @fleablood but keeping it that way generally works

Comment: I didnt say it wouldnt work.  I said you you claimed something that wasn't true.  If $\alpha$ is a root of one there are well known aspects about $\alpha^k$ and about $1+\alpha + \alpha^2 + .... + a^{n-1}$.   But $\alpha^6 = 1$ has $6$ solutions.  all but $\alpha = 1$ of which will yield the same least prime.  But claiming that $\alpha$ has  one solution is an untrue statement.

Comment: Is that $|stuff]$ supposed to be absolute value or square brackets?

Comment: @fleablood please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\begin{align}|z_1+z_2\alpha^r|^2&=(z_1+z_2\alpha^r)(z_1^\ast+z_2^\ast\alpha^{-r})\\&=z_1z_1^\ast+z_2z_2^\ast+2\Re[z_1^\ast z_2\alpha^r],\end{align}$$we obtain$$S=6(z_1z_1^\ast+z_2z_2^\ast)+2\Re\left[z_1^\ast z_2\underbrace{\frac{\alpha^6-1}{\alpha-1}}_{0}\right]=6(z_1z_1^\ast+z_2z_2^\ast),$$making its smallest prime factor $2$. Note we don't even need to calculate $S$ (although it's clearly $6(3^2+4^2+2^2+1^2)=180$).

Comment: I understand that $|z|^2=z.z*$ (I am assuming by * you mean the conjugate). But I don’t get how it applies in the first line.

Comment: @Aditya Do you understand$$(z_1+z_2\alpha^r)^\ast=z_1^\ast+(z_2\alpha^r)^\ast=z_1^\ast+z_2^\ast(\alpha^r)^\ast=z_1^\ast+z_2^\ast\alpha^{-r},$$where the last step uses the fact that $\alpha$ is a unit complex number?

Comment: Does * mean the conjugate of the complex number?

Comment: Also why does$ 2Re(z_1*z_2\alpha^r)$ come? Multiplying the initial two terms gives us $z_1z_1*$ and $z_2z_2*$ and $z_1*z_2\alpha^r+z_1z_2*\alpha^{-r}$

Comment: @Aditya $z^\ast$ is indeed the complex conjugate of $z$. Then I used $z+z^\ast=2\Re z$ to tidy up the "cross terms" (the ones that aren't of the form $zz^\ast$). BTW if you type `z^\ast` your star will be a superscript.